# Handle Java daylight saving based on different time zone from UTC (joda Interval)

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I need to return `List<Interval> intervals` based on the input I get from users. everything works fine unless the range includes daylight saving. If that happens the response I get is kinda messed up after that specific day (in this example Nov 1st EST time zone).

Since my data is stored as UTC in DB I am working with UTC (the request is in UTC and my response is also in UTC), however, in the browser, the time is converted into local timezone. In the backend, I have access to user timezone.
Now the question is how can I convert the response time to UTC that includes the daylight saving time.

```
public List<Interval> buildIntervals(BinInterval binSize) {
    final DateTime intervalStart = binSize.getInterval().getStart();
    final DateTime intervalEnd = binSize.getInterval().getEnd();

    final DateTimeZone tz = getCurrentUserTimezone();
    List<Interval> intervals = new ArrayList<>();

    MutableDateTime currentBinStart = new MutableDateTime(intervalStart);
    MutableDateTime currentBinEnd = new MutableDateTime(intervalStart.plus(binSize.getPeriod()));

    while (currentBinEnd.isBefore(intervalEnd)) {

    intervals.add(makeInterval(currentBinStart, currentBinEnd));

        currentBinStart = new MutableDateTime(currentBinStart.toDateTime().plus(binSize.getPeriod()));
        currentBinEnd = new MutableDateTime(currentBinEnd.toDateTime().plus(binSize.getPeriod()));

    }
} 

private static Interval makeInterval(BaseDateTime start, BaseDateTime end) {
    return new Interval(start.toDateTime().withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC),
                        end.toDateTime().withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC));
}
```

Here is sample response which is wrong:

The correct version for row 17 should be : `endDate: "2015-11-02T05:00:00.000z"`

[image]

From row 17 and further, the end time should be +5.
From row 18 and further the Start time should be +5 too, but for some reason, it doesn't convert time in the right way before and after daylight saving.

If I select a range after Nov 1st it works perfectly and converts it all to +5.

My local time zone is EST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you need to create intervals of different size for special cases that daylight saving is happening.

I suggest to get the offset of start time and end time and based on the values you can decide if you need to shift your end date or not.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateTimeZone EDT = DateTimeZone.forID("America/Toronto");
    DateTime start = new DateTime(2016, 5, 15, 4, 0, DateTimeZone.UTC);
    DateTime end = start.plusDays(2);

    int offset1 = (int) TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(EDT.getOffset(start.getMillis()));
    int offset2  = (int) TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(EDT.getOffset(end.getMillis()));
    if (offset1 != offset2) {
        end = end.plusMinutes(offset1 - offset2);
    }

    System.out.println(new Interval(start.toDateTime().withZone(EDT),
            end.toDateTime().withZone(EDT)));

}
```